# NavigationLink in Detail Page

Tags: swiftui

hey folk I have a problem I wanna make a NavationLink in Detail Page to show other Fruits. but when I click it it will make a page(with NavigationView) inside a Parent’s Page actually I want to replace it, not push a new one. this is my code

```
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        ScrollView(showsIndicators:false) {
            VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 20) {
                // HEADER
                FruitHeaderView(Fruit: fruit)
                VStack(alignment:.leading,spacing:20) {
                    // TITLE
                    Text("\(fruit.title)")
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .fontWeight(.heavy)
                        .foregroundColor(fruit.gradientColors[1])
                    // HEADLINE
                    Text("\(fruit.headline)")
                        .font(.headline)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                    // SUBHEADING
                    Text("Learn more about \(fruit.title)".uppercased())
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .foregroundColor(fruit.gradientColors[1])
                    // DESCRIPTION
                    Text("\(fruit.description)")
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                } //: VSTACK
                .padding(.horizontal,20)
                .frame(maxWidth:640,alignment: .center)
            } //: VSTACK
            VStack(alignment:.leading) {
                Text("Other Fruit like \(fruit.title)")
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .foregroundColor(fruit.gradientColors[1])
                ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators:false) {
                    HStack(spacing:30) {
                        ForEach(5...10,id:\.self) { item in
                            NavigationLink(destination: FruitDetailView(fruit: fruitsData[item])) {
                                AlternativeFruitView(Fruit: fruitsData[item])
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .padding(.horizontal,20)
            .frame(maxWidth:640,alignment: .center)
          
        } //: SCROLL
        .navigationBarTitle("\(fruit.title)",displayMode: .inline)
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
    } //: NAVIGATION
    .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle()) // iPad OS
}
```

and this is the result

| current Build | My Problem |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

I know there will be calling my struct and making a new NavigationView I just wanna know is is there an API or function that I can fix my problem or not
thanks.

Comment: You should only have `NavigationView` in *one* `View` at the top of your view hierarchy. Remove the others. There is not going to be an API to "remove" it from the hierarchy.

Comment: A `NavigationLink` will always push a new view, but that is the behavior you want here. As @jnpdx said, the issue with your multiple back buttons is simply that you have multiple `NavigationViews`.  I would also avoid fixed frames like that as they will not look good in other devices.

Comment: @jnpdx if I delete my NavigationView then how can I use **NavigationLink** to change my page!! thanks for your help.

Comment: You should have *one* NavigationView at the top of your view hierarchy